# set VideoView in BaseAdapter for ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

im quit new to Programming and Android in general. 
I want to have my VideoView in its own class and call it in the getView() method in my BaseAdapter, so i don't have everything in my Switch case.

Here is my getView() method right now. I know the MOKVideoView videoView = new MOKVideoView(context); part isn't right, but i can't figure out how to call it.

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int resource = 0;

    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
        case 0:
            resource = R.layout.headline_item;
            break;
        case 1:
            resource = R.layout.videoplayer_item;
            break;
    }

    View rowView = convertView;

    if (rowView == null) {
        rowView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(resource, null);
    }

    switch (resource){
        case R.layout.headline_item:
            TextView headline = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.headline);
            headline.setText("Hey Hey");
            break;
        case R.layout.videoplayer_item:
            MOKVideoView videoView = new MOKVideoView(context);
            return videoView.getmVideoView();
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

and here my MOKVideoView class

```
public MOKVideoView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initVideoView();
}

public MOKVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
    initVideoView();
}

public MOKVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initVideoView();
}

public View initVideoView() {
    View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.videoplayer_item, null, false);
    mVideoView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.video);
    countDownText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timer);
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);

    try {
        //set the uri of the video to be played
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.test_vid));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

sorry for the bad explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I get your question right. Do you mean that you want to create video view for each element of listview? If so you have to create an xml file with the video view and let your adapter expan d it.

Ex:

```
listview_item.xml:
<linearLayout
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height = "fill_parent"

    <MOKVideoView     
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
        android:id = "MOKVideo" />

</linearLayout>
```

and in your adapter you can call findViewById() to find the video view:

```
MOKVideoView mokvideo = (MOKVideoView) getView.findViewById(R.id.MOKVideo);
```

Comment: Thanks, i figured it out after saw your post :). Didn't know this was possible.